# How to curve deform a line of points - of specific uneven distances - and then instance on these points following the curve's rotation?

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, instances

I started with this:

[image]

... And I was able to deform it to the curve with correct rotation like that below - but the points are all in the same position. How do I offset them individually on the curve by the original distances?

[image]

---

PS: The indexes of the points are not in order of X axis position (I don't know if that's important?). It's made of 3 mesh lines, each one corresponds to a place on the repeating pattern. The indexes have this kind of order:

[image]

---

All tutorials, posts I found were using Curve to Points (which are even distances), or complex Curve Deform nodes that deform meshes (works but is overkill for this case). I just wanted to "map" a simple straight offset of points along a curve with the correspondent offset.

Could anybody help me please?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can map the $x$ coordinate to the curve factor:

[image]

[image]

As the OP already figured, the setup requires a slight adjustment if you don't want to "fill" the curve and instead want to maintain the original distances:

[image]

Comment: I think the OP wants the length instead of the factor.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the help. This one stretches the distances to fit the curve tho. How do I make the distances along the curve the same as the original ones?

Edit: Yes @lemon
I tried changing the sample curve to length earlier but it didn't work as what's before is done for factor. i don't know what to change.

Comment: Oh, I think I got it. I changed it to "length", deleted the Attribute Statistic and Map Range nodes and connected the X value directly to the "length" on the Sample Curve. And to offset it i added an Add math node before connecting the X onto length!